# How to fill out a list from the database?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I need to bind to each alias its rating, which would then display in the template, and order products by decreasing. How can I do that?

```
class Items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='Название товара', default='')
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='Цена')
    # image = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Картинка', default='')
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='image/', verbose_name='Изображение')
    alias = models.SlugField(verbose_name='Alias товара', default='')
    rating = models.FloatField(default=0, verbose_name='Рейтинг')



def popular(request):
    title = 'Популярные'
    products = Items.objects.all()
    category = Category.objects.all()

    context = {
        'products': products,
        'category': category,
        'title': title,
    }
    return render(request, 'popular/main.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the result set from the database by ordering it the way you want:

```
products = Items.objects.order_by('-rating')
```

And in the template:

```
{% for product in products %}
    {{product.alias}} - {{product.rating}}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much!